OTPs and Authentication Tables
When I was in the USAF, we used (practice) authentication tables in our training to prepare radio traffic (the tables we would use in wartime were secured). Are the principles used to create authentication tables the same as for creating OTPs? Thanks.

Welcome Mr Beaver :-)  For us civis, are these similar to those pre-made plastic authentication cards you see in films like Crimson Tide? They snap them open and compare to the code in the message?

I guess the answer is yes, but if I ask ChatGPT then it seems KDF's are also an option if devices were being used. As this seems historical I don't think that counts. How the randomized values are produced and distributed is entirely up to the users of these schemes, but then again: the same goes for OTP's if you ask me.

@MaartenBodewes What did your Magic 8 Ball say?  I find my Magic 8 Ball is about as accurate as ChatGPT, but uses much less energy. ;)

If it actually names devices I'm slightly more inclined to believe it. My magic 8-ball says "you may rely on it" but I'm doubtful.

@EndAntisemiticHate Interesting.  De facto Magic 8 Ball here powered by an example of a DIY entropy source. And I believe that you can rely on it to be totally random, consuming only a few Watts.

@PaulUszak That's a great site you referenced.  Thank you for linking to it.
